# tensoflow sparse tensor efficient batching

Tags: tensorflow

I have a method (shown below) that gets a batch from a tensorflow SparseTensorValue. However, this method is rather slow (10-20 seconds for a batch of size 32), which is problematic because it's called thousands of times.

```
def get_batch(index, tensors, batch_size, nItems):
    xs, ys = tensors
    begin = (index * batch_size)
    end = min((index+1)*batch_size, nItems)
    y_b = ys[begin:end]

    (inds, vals, dsize) = xs
    nInds = [[ind[0] - begin, ind[1]] for ind in inds if begin <= ind[0] < end]
    nInds = np.array(nInds)
    nVals = vals[:nInds.shape[0]]
    nDsize = (end - begin, dsize[1])
    x_b = tf.SparseTensorValue(nInds, nVals, nDsize)
    return (x_b, y_b)
```

Is there a way to make this method more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to write your input pipeline using `tf.data` instead, then if anything you can offload this rebatching to another core and not block your main thread.